# How to handle callback in content script from background script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am sending message to background script and receive data in listener,

**in content script"**

```
function sendData(formdata,callback){
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: formdata, method:
 'storeform'},function(response) {
              console.log(response.data);   
 });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
     if(request.method == "storeform")
     {
        //do some work

        });             
    }
```

I need to call, callback function of sendData() from listener. 
Inbetween there are multiple messages and process between content script and background script. Please help.
Here the return from background script is in form of chrome.runtime.sendMessage.

Comment: Did you try passing the callback to Listener function as the last parameter ? I mean if you want to execute a callback well just pass it.

Comment: is it possbile? because these are two different funtions. the sec one is called from background script. I want to know how to transfer callback function as parameter to the background script.

Comment: the second is not called from the background script, it's called from content script itself but when background script sends a message to content script event occurs.

Comment: exactly. when background script send message the listener is trigger.  i need to call the callback of method 1 in listener

Comment: your callback function is located where ?

Comment: post your callback function

Comment: callback is in sendData() in content script.

Comment: are you sure sendData is your callback ? if yes then in which function are you passing it as a callback ?

Comment: no the callback is not the sendData, its parameter of sendData.  sendData is called from another content script. this trigger background scipt through onMessage, the backgroung calls a function in another content script. and after execution, it calls the main content script with onMessage. I need to call the callback of sendData

Comment: You can use callbacks like any regular javascript code here also but if you think otherwise, please attach callback function definition and let me know the issue that you are facing in calling it ?

Comment: I can use the callback. but i need to trigger it from the Listener. which is totally different function

Comment: https://www.dashingd3js.com/lessons/javascript-callback-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages are just JSON; they can't include functions.  From the content script, save a reference to the callback function, then include that id when passing messages between the content and background scripts.  When you're done with all the intermediate processing, send a message to tell the content script to run the callback.  When the content script receives a message with a callback id, look up the callback function and call it.

**content script**

```
var callbacks = {};

function sendData(formdata, callback) {
  // good-enough unique id
  var callbackId = (new Date()).getTime();
  callbacks[callbackId] = callback;
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      data: formdata,
      method: 'storeform',
      callbackId,
  }, function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);   
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
     // if message includes a callback id, call it
     if (request.callbackId && callbacks[request.callbackId]) {
         callbacks[request.callbackId]();
     }
  }          
)
```

**background script**

```
// everything done; call the callback
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({callbackId});
```

Answer (score -1):

As specified in the question, the `message` that is sent should be an object (`{data: formdata, method: 'storeform'}`), but you [can send any messages that you can `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-sendMessage),

### Simple, generic example

In the example below, the message is the string `'Hello background script!'`.

```js
function sendMessageFromTab() {
    const script = `
        (function() {
            const message = 'Hello background script!';

            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
        })();
    `;

    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: script
    });
}

function listenForMessages() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
        console.log('Received message:', message);
    });
}


chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    // ^ Run the code e.g. when clicking the icon of the Extension
    listenForMessages();
    sendMessageFromTab();
});
```